# Search for a string in multiple tables and get specific fields with Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a global search form, now I need the good query.

So from my form, I retrieve a keyword.

From this keyword I want to find all Tasks, Users, Projects, and more where this keyword is present.

Furthermore I need only 2 or 3 fields by table (generally an id and a title).

I had some problems before to do this so I ask it here.
How can I do that from my controller in one query? Do you have any good examples?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some codes? Are these entities joined to each other? Do you want to join them? If yes base on what?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of building query manually, I suggest to use this good bundle [LexikFormFilterBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle),

to understand how to use it see this [simple example](https://github.com/lexik/LexikFormFilterBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#simple-example)